# Possible to make a managed (non-GDI) Bitmap?

Tags: c#, gdi+

Is it possible to make a fully managed code Bitmap object? My understanding is the Bitmap object is a wrapper around a GDI object - which is unmanaged code.

I am interesting in doing this to (hopefully) increase performance when dealing with thousands of images.

Answer (score 1):

Never had a problem with the Bitmap object.

Conventional thinking is that unmanaged code is marginally faster than managed code, so it's strange that you perceive a performance increase in going the other way around...

Comment: I have issues with the Dispose() method releasing the GDI+ handle on every object. Seems to be where ANTS Profiler is saying is my biggest bottleneck. Hopefully I am just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to recommend looking at Paint.NET's source code, but it looks like it's not available anymore :(. Which is a shame, since it has a lot of good stuff on bitmaps. However, I discovered this: http://code.google.com/p/paint-mono/, maybe it could help you with your question

Comment: Huh?! Indeed not available anymore. Boo.